# How to get the final output shape of Network (derived from nn.Module)?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

**What is the `Pytorch` equivalent of**:

```
model.layers[-1].output_shape # tensorflow model

OR

model.get_layer('conv3d_0').output_shape # tensorflow model
```

Looking the module given below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class ConvolutionBlock(nn.Module):
    '''
    The basic Convolution Block Which Will have Convolution -> RelU -> Convolution -> RelU
    '''
    def __init__(self, input_features, out_features):
        '''
        args:
            batch_norm was introduced after UNET so they did not know if it existed. Might be useful
        '''
        super().__init__()
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(input_features, out_features, kernel_size = 3, padding= 0), # padding is 0 by default, 1 means the input width, height == out width, height
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(out_features, out_features, kernel_size = 3, padding = 0),
            nn.ReLU(),
            )

    def forward(self, feature_map_x):
        '''
        feature_map_x could be the image itself or the
        '''
        return self.network(feature_map_x)
```

when I do: `ConvolutionBlock(8,16)`, I know my output will have `16` channels but what if I want to instantiate my block dynamically and try to read the output shape somewhere else? How could I do it?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by *"instantiate my block dynamically"*?

Comment: I mean given some input size by user while calling a function? Let us ignore this part in case if it is wrong. Any ideas on how to get the output shapes?

Comment: You could perform inference with random data given the input dimensions, no?

Comment: Not really. The idea is to wrap this class inside some other class and build a network from there. Just like `keras` layers infer the shapes automatically.